# Sharepoint Build in Services MSSQL/MSSQLFT

Tags: web-services

Does every SharePoint instance include a built-in MSSQLFT?

I am asking this because I am writing a tool which sends an MSSQLFT Query over the web services `/_vti_bin/search.asmx`

I want that tool to work with every SharePoint instance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't use MSSQLFT against SharePoint with FAST, so the best option is to use keyword queries if you want broad reach ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms573544.aspx))

Comment: Thx for the very fast answer:
So you say to use: 

<QueryText language=xml:lang type={STRING|MSSQLFT|FQL}>
searchQuery
</QueryText>

And as Type to use "STRING" because :
STRING
Applies to: Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 search and Microsoft FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint
Indicates that the kind of query is keyword query. For information, see Keyword Query Syntax Reference.

?!

Comment: Yes type="String" and then the query as Keyword syntax gives you the broadest reach

Comment: Thank you very much.
Sometimes its very difficult to find answers like this over the documentations of Microsoft.

Comment: That why we have this site ;-)